# Multiple nested select dropdown list dependent on input element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have input element as range for years. I can change value of year by buttons. I would like to create nested list in second select that depends on year from range input and on first select - id countrySelect.

```
<input type="range" id="yearRange" min="0" max="3" list="yearsDatalist" value="3"
onChange="changeYear(value)" onInput="changeYearLite(value)">
    <datalist id="yearsDatalist">
        <option value="0" label="1918"></option>
        <option value="1" label="1936"></option>
        <option value="2" label="1950"></option>
        <option value="3" label="1981"></option>
    </datalist>
```

Then I have two select elements. The first one is static - not necessary to change the values there:

```
<select id="countrySelect">
    <option value="0">Sweden</option>
    <option value="1">Germany</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>
```

Second select is dependent on year and on values in first select with `id=countrySelect`

```
<select id="itemSelection"></select>
```

I used object for values like this in some different project:

```
const yearsFilterDataList = {
    "1918": {
        "0": "Choose model",
        "volvo": "Volvo",
        "mercedes": "Mercedes",
        "saab": "Saab"
    }, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [template literal for string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) in a `querySelector` to find the label attribute on the selected option.

```
function changeYear (value) {
  let selectedOption = document.querySelector(`option[value="${value}"]`);
  let selectedYear = selectedOption.label;
  
  let data = yearsFilterDataList[selectedYear];
  // Do what you want with the car information
}
```

Next time try to provide and organize your code (HTML, CSS, JS) in a better way so people don't have to guess what your setup exactly is. You also didn't provide the full `yearsFilterDataList` object so the slider only populates the select form on the first tick.

But here is an assumed implementation:

```js
const yearsFilterDataList = {
    "1918": {
        "0": "Choose model",
        "volvo": "Volvo",
        "mercedes": "Mercedes",
        "saab": "Saab"
    }
}

function changeYearLite (value) {
    // ?
}
    
function changeYear (value) {
  let selectedOption = document.querySelector(`option[value="${value}"]`);
  let selectedYear = selectedOption.label;
  
  let data = yearsFilterDataList[selectedYear];
  if (!data) return console.warn('no data found')
  let wrapper = document.getElementById('itemSelection');
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index) => {
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = index;
      option.textContent = data[key];
      wrapper.appendChild(option);
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="yearRange" min="0" max="3" list="yearsDatalist" value="3"
onChange="changeYear(value)" onInput="changeYearLite(value)">
<datalist id="yearsDatalist">
  <option value="0" label="1918"></option>
  <option value="1" label="1936"></option>
  <option value="2" label="1950"></option>
  <option value="3" label="1981"></option>
</datalist>

<select id="countrySelect">
    <option value="0">Sweden</option>
    <option value="1">Germany</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>

<select id="itemSelection"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle where I have created an `optgroup` for each year-country pair, each optgroup has two elements, depending on the ids of the year and country (you can of course change the options of each `optgroup`, the lone reason for this kind of `option` definition was to ease my testing). Changing the value of `yearRange` or `yearsDatalist` triggers a call to `changeOptions`, which finds these elements, defines the `id` of the `optgroup` to show, then loops the optgroups and hides everything except the one that matches the `id`. The matching `optgroup` will be shown and, since any prior selection is logically invalidated, I update `itemSelection.value` to the value of the first child of the chosen `optgroup`.

Finally I call `changeOptions` anyway, in order to initialize a proper state even before any of the triggers are triggered.

```js
function changeOptions() {
    let yearRange = document.getElementById("yearRange").value;
    let countrySelect = document.getElementById("countrySelect").value;
    let id = `options-${yearRange}-${countrySelect}`;
    let itemSelection = document.getElementById("itemSelection");
    for (let optgroup of itemSelection.children) {
        let match = optgroup.id === id;
        optgroup[(match ? "remove" : "set") + "Attribute"]("hidden", "hidden");
        if (match) {
            itemSelection.value = optgroup.children[0].value;
        }
    }
}

changeOptions();
```

```html
<input type="range" id="yearRange" min="0" max="3" list="yearsDatalist" value="3"
onChange="changeOptions()" onInput="changeOptions()">
    <datalist id="yearsDatalist">
        <option value="0" label="1918"></option>
        <option value="1" label="1936"></option>
        <option value="2" label="1950"></option>
        <option value="3" label="1981"></option>
    </datalist>

<select id="countrySelect" onchange="changeOptions()">
    <option value="0">Sweden</option>
    <option value="1">Germany</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>

<select id="itemSelection">
    <optgroup id="options-0-0">
        <option value="0-0-1">0-0-1</option>
        <option value="0-0-1">0-0-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-0-1">
        <option value="0-1-1">0-1-1</option>
        <option value="0-1-1">0-1-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-0-2">
        <option value="0-2-1">0-2-1</option>
        <option value="0-2-1">0-2-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-0-3">
        <option value="0-3-1">0-3-1</option>
        <option value="0-3-1">0-3-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-1-0">
        <option value="1-0-1">1-0-1</option>
        <option value="1-0-1">1-0-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-1-1">
        <option value="1-1-1">1-1-1</option>
        <option value="1-1-1">1-1-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-1-2">
        <option value="1-2-1">1-2-1</option>
        <option value="1-2-1">1-2-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-1-3">
        <option value="1-3-1">1-3-1</option>
        <option value="1-3-1">1-3-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-2-0">
        <option value="2-0-1">2-0-1</option>
        <option value="2-0-1">2-0-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-2-1">
        <option value="2-1-1">2-1-1</option>
        <option value="2-1-1">2-1-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-2-2">
        <option value="2-2-1">2-2-1</option>
        <option value="2-2-1">2-2-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-2-3">
        <option value="2-3-1">2-3-1</option>
        <option value="2-3-1">2-3-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-3-0">
        <option value="3-0-1">3-0-1</option>
        <option value="3-0-1">3-0-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-3-1">
        <option value="3-1-1">3-1-1</option>
        <option value="3-1-1">3-1-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-3-2">
        <option value="3-2-1">3-2-1</option>
        <option value="3-2-1">3-2-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="options-3-3">
        <option value="3-3-1">3-3-1</option>
        <option value="3-3-1">3-3-2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```